# Exporting Contacts into csv file automatically format mobile numbers into scientific

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

Into my project when i m exporting Contacts into csv file automatically format mobile numbers  starts with 91 into scientific.

e.g
mobile no into exporting data

919433454320

mobile no into csv file when scientific format

9.194E+11

after format cell as number with 0 decimal places

919430000000

For exporting contacts into my project i m using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Workbook 
here is my code

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = false;
            Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            object[,] rawData = new object[DataTable.Rows.Count + 1, DataTable.Columns.Count];

            for (int col = 0; col < DataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                rawData[0, col] = DataTable.Columns[col].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int col = 0; col < DataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < DataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    rawData[row + 1, col] = DataTable.Rows[row].ItemArray[col];
                }
            }
            string[] callchar = new string[]  {"range of my excel sheet (e.g from a to Bz"};
            string excelRange = callchar[0] + "1:" + callchar[DataTable.Columns.Count - 1] + (DataTable.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
            Range r = ws.Cells.EntireColumn.NumberFormat;
            ws.get_Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData;
            wb.SaveAs(Filename: FilePath, FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, ReadOnlyRecommended: false);
            wb.Close();
            app.Quit();
```

Comment: try formatting the column as "Text" format

Comment: Try adding the mobile number wrapped with double quotes ("")

Comment: i want to export mobile no @PeterAlbert

Comment: Wrapping mobilenumbers into double quotes display as "919433454320".

Comment: I think there is no way to tell implicitly which data type you have in CSV for the importing software(in our case - MS Excel). You may consider either another way of exporting data or some sort of postprocessing of your data after importing.

Comment: @Sinatr please refer my edited que.

Comment: *confused*, CSV-format is so simple, are you using excel just to generate CSV or do you generate CSV to import into MS Excel? And where do you get your mobile number changed to scientific: in CSV or 1) in Excel before making CSV 2) in Excel after importing?

Comment: @Sinatr i m using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` to generate csv files. if i open generated csv with notepad still the numbers are displayed in scientific format

Comment: Then why do you need Excel? :D `file.WriteLine("1;2;3;4;5");` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use late binding to export data:

```
            // try to open excel
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Type typeExcelApplication = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
            if (typeExcelApplication == null)
                throw new Exception("Excel is not installed (Excel.Application is not found)");
            object objExcelApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(typeExcelApplication);
            object objWorkBooks = objExcelApplication.GetType().InvokeMember("Workbooks", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, objExcelApplication, null);
            object objWorkBook = objWorkBooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objWorkBooks, null);
            object objWorkSheet = objWorkBook.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveSheet", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, objWorkBook, null);

            // fill data (put object obj into cell [1,1])
            objWorkSheet.GetType().InvokeMember("Cells", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objWorkSheet, new object[] { 1, 1, obj});

            // display excel
            typeExcelApplication.InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, objExcelApplication, new object[] { true });
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objExcelApplication);
```

Excel should properly process types, so if you supply `obj` as a **`string`** - it will not try to make a number (scientific?) from it.

Comment: I have more cells so may be it will slow my process can i do it with range @Sinatr

Comment: It should be possible, try to dig [`around`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389881/late-binding-excel-with-net)