# How to format exponent to number from Export to excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am exporting data table to excel and one column is having Phone number in the data table but after export in Excel the phone number coloumn is displaying as exponent.

I need as number, How to fix this ?

```
 string fileName = "File" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmss") + ".xls";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=File.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        DataGrid dataExportExcel = new DataGrid();
        dataExportExcel.ItemDataBound += new DataGridItemEventHandler(dataExportExcel_ItemDataBound);
        dataExportExcel.DataSource = dt;
        dataExportExcel.DataBind();
        dataExportExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbResponseString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sbResponseString.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:xlExcel8\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> <head></head> <body>");
        sbResponseString.Append(stringWriter + "</body></html>");
        Response.Write(sbResponseString.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Comment: same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024367/exporting-contacts-into-csv-file-automatically-format-mobile-numbers-into-scient#comment21113659_15024367) ?

Comment: You want to programmatically put a single apostrophe infront of the phone number

Comment: Is that helps to my problem?
The above code i am writing as export to excel, Is there any other best option is there?
I am converting the datatable to html, Actually i need the datable to be export to excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this
 td { mso-number-format:"@"; }

Answer (score 4):

Add the below **STYLE** to your HTML tag, It will help you..

```
<style> table { mso-number-format:'0'; } </style>
```

**like this :**

```
sbResponseString.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:xlExcel8\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> <head><style> td { mso-number-format:'0'; } </style></head> <body>");
```

**Full Code:**

```
   protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("Phone");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        DataRow Sample = dt.NewRow();
        Sample["Phone"] = 125316245612456124;
        Sample["Name"] = "Pandian";
        dt.Rows.Add(Sample);
        GetExcel(dt);            
    }
    public void GetExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        string fileName = "File" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmss") + ".xls";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        DataGrid dataExportExcel = new DataGrid();
        dataExportExcel.DataSource = dt;
        dataExportExcel.DataBind();
        dataExportExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbResponseString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sbResponseString.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:xlExcel8\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> <head><style> table { mso-number-format:'0'; } </style></head> <body>");
        sbResponseString.Append(stringWriter + "</body></html>");
        Response.Write(sbResponseString.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

**Excel Output :**

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: Hi pandian
Its not working with Characters more than 500 and for date cells
please help me what format is preferred ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NumberValue  and NumberFormat properties`

Here a sample, set your range

```
yourSheet.Range[".."].NumberValue = 1234.5678;
yourSheet.Range[".."].NumberFormat = "0.00";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can prepend a single quote to the phone number before writing it to the cell of the spreadsheat.

like "'1234567890" instead of "1234567890"

thanks